# Jenkins - SSH from Job's shell to jenkins

Tags: jenkins, ssh

What i am trying seems quite simple, but i cant really get my head wrapped around what i need to do:

Inside a job, i have a build-step that executes shell-commands. This shell command tries using the Jenkins CLI. 
So basically it says "java -jar theCliFile -s jenkinsURL / command

So inside of a job, i am trying to make a SSH connection to the jenkins-server itself.

This fails, console output says that "[WARN] Failed to authenticate with your SSH keys. Proceeding as anonymous
You must authenticate to access this Jenkins.".

I could provide a username and password as clear text inside of the shell, but i would like to avoid that.

What do i need to setup in order to allow an automatic authentication? I don't understand who needs what kind of keys.

The [Jenkins CLI Wiki](http://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+CLI) says to configured a /me/configure user. I just don't see how this makes sense. I guess this was meant to be for use cases where someone tries to build a SSH connection from a remote machine, not from the Jenkins itself, as in my case.

Comment: please, post the solution to an answer or delete question. Do not post answers as edit.

Comment: I'll post it as answer, It might become handy to some people searchin it. I myself has no success using google to find an answer to this case, so someone else might be having similar trouble. I had edited because at that time i could not submit an answer yet. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, i solved it myself:

I had both a private and public key on the Jenkins-Server (incase you don't have those, just generate them on the server machine that the Jenkins runs on (there are tons of tutorials on how to do so out there)).

To allow what i was trying in my question, i had to take the public key and enter it in some user existing for the jenkins-application.
As far as i understand, entering the Jenkins Servers public key in any user will make the SSH request authenticate as this user and thus the shell will have the rights of said user.